# CSS selector for all the input that have a parent div with id name starts with property

Tags: css

I can select all IDs that start with a string:

`[id^="datore-node-form"]`

and the input with an attribute of a specific div:

`#user-pass input[type="submit"]`

But how can I select the `input[type="submit"]` of all div that starts with?

This doesn't work
`[id^="datore-node-form"] input[type="submit"]`

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Could you post some example code? Consider sticking the '>'  operator in between `[id^="datore-node-form"]` and `input[type="submit"]`

Comment: try using a direct decendance pointer `>` like so `[id^="datore-node-form"] > input[type="submit"]{}`

Comment: @kennytm: the input don't take the style
@s

Comment: @PonzioPilato Perhaps you should paste a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kennytm: here it is http://pasteboard.co/zLM0fU7rh.png

Comment: @SamJudge: doesn't work

Comment: Since there is nothing wrong with the selctors, you either have wrong selector value or markup structure. For us to be able to help we need to see both, as code (text, not as image), so we can test it